# How can I run a method outside rxjs Observable when extending Angular2 HTTP Client?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, ionic2, angular2-http

i'm creating a HttpClient for my Angular2 typescript app and I'm stuck in error handler.

I want to emit an event when I catch a 401 error, and I'm able to catch the error but not to trigger my event, because the .catch needs to be attached to a function of type Observable, so I dont have access of my HttpClient Class **this** scope.

```js
errorHandler (error:any) : Observable<any> {
  if(error.status == 401) {
    // I want to call this.myOtherMethod() here!
    this.events.publish('token_expired'); // Will throw this.events is undefined
    console.log(error);
  }

  return Observable.throw(error.json());
}

get(url) : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(url, {
    headers: this.customHeaders
  }).catch( this.errorHandler );
}
```

So I know I cant access my this.events from inside this function, but what's the workaround? How can I inject the events there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you reference the `errorHandler` method so you lose the value of the `this` keyword. It's the way JavaScript works.

You could try the following to prevent from this:

```
get(url) : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(url, {
    headers: this.customHeaders
  }).catch( (error:any) => {
    return this.errorHandler(error);
  });
}
```

or

```
get(url) : Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get(url, {
    headers: this.customHeaders
  }).catch( this.errorHandler.bind(this) );
}
```

You need to be aware of the drawback when using the `bind` method with TypeScript:

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/bind.html

Comment: Perfectly answered! Worked like a charm. I was way too worried about the function type and I didn't noticed the scope killing reference. Thank You!

Marked as solved.